# Change date Format in jQuery DatePicker to English dd/mm/yy?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to format the date of a jQuery DatePicker to the English format 'dd-mm-yy', but I'm unable to get it to work.  I've looked at all of the answers on this site and they all are using the same code as I am.  Any idea why mine is not working?  I have tried the two following ways:

```
$(function () {
    $(".datefield").datepicker({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'});
});

$(function () {
    $(".datefield").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
});
```

Neither of these have worked.  I was wondering if I had to include some other jQuery file to get the date to format to English.

Any help, as always, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle for your application as this seems to work per se, if you want to change the format afterwards check out starx answer

Comment: Hiya works here man - check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/cyM5K/1/

Comment: My apologies to you both.  I've recently changed from using IE to FireFox for my development and I'd failed to disable the cache.  I'm sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to change it, use the setter method

```
$( ".datefield" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
```

Comment: My apologies to you. I've recently changed from using IE to FireFox for my development and I'd failed to disable the cache. I'm sorry to have wasted your time.